# Put child actions in parent component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i have a component that make an api call and summarize a text. This component is named TextSummarizer. I want to reset summary, copy or download the summary generated, but the buttons should be placed in parent because it can be in header or in footer or in different sides. How can i run actions like resetSummary(), or copyText() from buttons in parent?

**Parent**

```
<HeaderLayout>
<UButton>Reset Summary</UButton>
</HeaderLayout>
<TextSummarizer/>
```

I'm thinking in use props like :reset="true" or "false" and watcher in child, also i've thought to use refs.resetSummary, or something like pass in props, what do you think that is best option to solve this? I want to put actions in parent because it can be palced in diferent positions depend of page.

**TextSummarizer.vue**

```
const resetSummary = () => {
  summaryResponse.value = {
    input_text: "",
    output_text: "",
  };
};
const copied = ref(false);
const copy = () => {
  copied.value = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    copied.value = false;
  }, 2000);
  return navigator.clipboard.writeText(
    summaryResponse.value.output_text.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""),
  );
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <UForm
      v-if="summaryResponse.output_text === ''"
      ref="form"
      :state="data"
      :schema="schema"
      class="space-y-4"
    >
      <UFormGroup
        :label="numberWords(data.text) + ' Palabras'"
        :hint="data.text.length + '/' + MAX_LENGTH + ' caracteres'"
        name="text"
      >
        <UTextarea
          v-model="data.text"
          placeholder="Pega el texto que quieres resumir"
          :rows="10"
        />
      </UFormGroup>
      <UFormGroup class="mt-4" name="language">
        <USelectMenu
          v-model="data.language"
          :options="languages"
          option-attribute="name"
          value-attribute="code"
        >
          <template #label>
            <UIcon :name="selectedLanguage?.icon" />
            {{ selectedLanguage?.name }}
          </template>
        </USelectMenu>
      </UFormGroup>
      <UFormGroup>
        <UTabs
          v-model="modeSelected"
          :items="modes"
          :ui="{
            list: {
              background: 'bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800',
            },
          }"
          @change="onSelectMode"
        >
          <template #default="{ item, selected }">
            <div class="flex items-center gap-2 relative truncate">
              <UIcon :name="item.icon" class="w-4 h-4 flex-shrink-0" />

              <span class="truncate">{{ item.label }}</span>

              <span
                v-if="selected"
                class="absolute -right-4 w-2 h-2 rounded-full bg-primary-500 dark:bg-primary-400"
              />
            </div>
          </template>
        </UTabs>
      </UFormGroup>
      <UFormGroup class="flex justify-end">
        <UButton
          label="Resumir"
          type="submit"
          :loading="inProgress"
          @click="user ? navigateTo('/tools/summarizer') : validateForm"
        />
      </UFormGroup>
    </UForm>
    <div v-else-if="summaryResponse.output_text" class="flex gap-8">
      <div
        v-if="summaryResponse.output_text"
        v-motion-fade
        class="relative transition-all duration-300"
        :class="showOriginalText ? 'w-1/2' : 'w-full'"
      >
        <span v-if="showOriginalText" class="font-bold mb-2 flex">Resumen</span>
        <div :class="showOriginalText ? 'p-4 border rounded-lg' : ''">
          <EditorTiptapEditor
            v-if="summaryResponse.input_text"
            v-model="summaryResponse.output_text"
            @editor-created="onEditorCreated($event)"
          />
        </div>

        <div
          v-if="!summaryResponse.input_text"
          v-html="summaryResponse.output_text"
        ></div>
        <div
          v-if="inProgress"
          class="absolute bottom-4 flex justify-center w-8 h-8 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 mx-auto bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-full"
        >
          <UIcon
            color="primary"
            class="animate-spin h-8 w-8 text-primary"
            name="i-ph-circle-notch"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        v-if="showOriginalText && summaryResponse.input_text"
        v-motion-fade
        class="w-1/2"
      >
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-2">
          <span class="font-bold">Texto original</span>
        </div>
        <div
          id="original-text"
          class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 overflow-auto border p-4 rounded-lg whitespace-pre-wrap"
          v-html="summaryResponse.input_text"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the purposes of a `composeable` is to extrapolate out UI state management in a way that it can be managed from components at any stage of the application. I'd suggest doing just that here.

Let's make a file in `composeables/useTextSummarizer.js`:

```js
const state = reactive({
  copied: false,
  summaryResponse: {
     input_text: "",
     output_text: "",
  }
})

export function useTextSummarizer () {
  const resetSummary = () => {
    state.summaryResponse.input_text = "";
    state.summaryResponse.output_text= "";
  };

  const copy = () => {
    state.copied = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      state.copied = false;
    }, 2000);
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      state.summaryResponse.output_text.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""),
    );
  };
    
  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    resetSummary,
    copy
  }
}
```

Now your parent can easily reset the text summarizer:

```js
import { useTextSummarizer } from '@/composeables/useTextSummarizer';

const { resetSummary } = useTextSummarizer();
```

```html
<HeaderLayout>
<UButton @click="resetSummary">Reset Summary</UButton>
</HeaderLayout>
<TextSummarizer/>
```

And your `TextSummarizer` component can manage the state of the composeable:

```js
import { useTextSummarizer } from '@/composeables/useTextSummarizer';

const { copied, summaryResponse } = useTextSummarizer();
```

The rest of the code in the component can stay the same, as we've casted the state values to `refs` so they are a `Proxy` with a `.value` property just like a `ref()` or `computed()`.